# Mac OS VSCode built-in terminal can't import installed python packages even the corrected conda environment selected

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Mac OS VSCode built-in terminal can't import installed python packages.

I've installed NumPy correctly using Anaconda in one of my environments called `tf20`;
And then I created a python script `scene.py`

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

I can run this script in my system Terminal like:

```
(tf20) mac@Macbook:~/Desktop/manim_project$ python scene.py
1.18.5
```

However, an import error occurred when I run the same script.

```
(tf20) mac@Macbook:~/Desktop/manim_project$ python scene.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scene.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

However, when I run this by pressing `F5`, the debug mode, the problem disappeared.

```
(tf20) mac@Macbook:~/Desktop/manim_project$  cd /Users/mac/Desktop/manim_project ; /usr/bin/env /Users/mac/.jackprogram/anaconda3/envs/tf20/bin/python /Users/mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 62372 -- /Users/mac/Desktop/manim_project/scene.py 
1.18.5
(tf20) mac@Macbook:~/Desktop/manim_project$
```

I think I selected the right python environment `tf20` in VSCode because

- the VSCode built-in terminal showed `(tf20)` at the beginning of the terminal prompt.
- the left corner of VSCode showed `Python3.7.7 64-bit ('tf20:conda')`.
- and I even used `cmd` + `shift` + `p` then `Python: Select Intereter` to ensure I selected the right python environment.

[image]

Because of this problem, I have to use the macOS terminal application to run the Python scripts for a half year.

Help. Please!

Comment: Sorry, but could you try to check which python you are using in the VSCode? Such as `python --version`, `which python`, `sys.executable` and so on...

Comment: And I feel puzzled of File `scene.py`, line 10, but it looks like should be line 1.

Comment: Thank you for the useful remind. I updated the results in the newly uploaded image. It shows it uses python 2.7 when running `python scene.py` in VSCode.

Comment: Yeah, it should be line 1. It showed line 10 because I have some commenting lines in the beginning, which I deleted when I took that screenshot.